# Django and HTML: Problem with Extra Space Around Navigation Bar

Tags: html, django

I am learning Django by building an application, called TravelBuddies. It will allow travelers to plan their trip and keep associated travel items (such as bookings, tickets, copy of passport, insurance information, etc), as well as create alerts for daily activities. The application will also able to update local information such as weather or daily news to the traveler. Travelers can also share the travel information with someone or have someone to collaborate with them to plan for the trip.

I am facing a problem. There is extra space at the top and bottom of the navigation bar.
[image]

How can I remove this extra white space on top and bottom of the navigation bar? I tried modifying the style codes. But I haven't managed to fix the issue.

Here are my codes in `triplist.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  {% block title%}Trip list{% endblock %}
  <title>Trip list</title>
</head>


<body>
  {% block content %}
  <!--Page content-->
  <h1>Upcoming Trips</h1><br>


  <ol>
    {% for trip in all_trips %}

    <li><a href="{% url 'trips:activity' trip.slug %}">Trip name: {{ trip.trip_name }}</a></li>
    <b>Date:</b> {{ trip.date }}<br>
    <b>Planner:</b> {{ trip.planner_name }}<br>
    <b>Coplanners:</b>
    {% for user in trip.add_coplanner.all %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
    {{user.username}}
    {% else %}
    {{user.username}},
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}<br>
    <b>Trip Description:</b> {{ trip.trip_description }}<br><br>
    <!--            Co-planner: {{ trip.add_coplanner.all }}<br>-->

    {% endfor %}
  </ol>




  <!--    <img src="{% static "images/botanical-garden.jpg" %}" alt="Botanical Garden" />-->
  <!-- New line -->
  {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Here are my codes in `base.html`:

```
<!--Result Size: 1392 x 239-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>{% block title %}

    {% endblock %}</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  ​
  <!--Logged in-->
  <!--Left side-->
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'trips:triplist' %}">TravelBuddies</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'trips:triplist'%}">Trip List</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'addtrip:addtrip'%}">Add Trip</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'addactivity:addactivity'%}">Add Activity</a></li>

          <!--
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="">
            <a href="">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
              {{ request.user.username }}
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'addtrip:logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  ​
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-left">


      {% else %}

      <!--Not Logged in-->
      <!--Left side-->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'trips:triplist' %}">TravelBuddies</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'trips:triplist' %}">Trip List</a></li>
              <!--
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        -->
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="{% url 'addtrip:register' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Register </a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'addtrip:login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      ​
      {% endif %}

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-left">

          {% block content %}

          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Remove ```<!DOCTYPE html>``` in your triplist.html file.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel I have removed it. But it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your base html keep the main tags which is required for a template as shown below:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

 <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
 </body>
```

And in other templates you don't have to use html tags or body tags because you are inheriting those from base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 Your html code goes here
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have tried your codes. But it doesn't fix the issue. Still, there are extra white spaces on the top and the bottom of the navigation bar.

Comment: try without your if tags, also right click and inspect element and see what causing the issue

Comment: I have tried the inspect element tool. But it doesn't inspect the area which has extra white space.

Answer (score 0):

Your triplist.html should be like this:

```
    {% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>Upcoming Trips</h1><br>


    <ol>
    {% for trip in all_trips %}

        <li><a href="{% url 'trips:activity' trip.slug %}">Trip name: {{ trip.trip_name }}</a></li>
        <b>Date:</b> {{ trip.date }}<br>
        <b>Planner:</b> {{ trip.planner_name }}<br>
        <b>Coplanners:</b>
            {% for user in trip.add_coplanner.all %}
                {% if forloop.last %}
                {{user.username}}
                {% else %}
                {{user.username}},
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}<br>
        <b>Trip Description:</b> {{ trip.trip_description }}<br><br>
       <!--Co-planner: {{ trip.add_coplanner.all }}<br>-->

    {% endfor %}
    </ol>




<!--<img src="{% static "images/botanical-garden.jpg" %}" alt="Botanical Garden" />-->
<!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried your codes. But it doesn't fix the issue. Still, there are extra white spaces on the top and the bottom of the navigation bar.

Comment: @Shawn, Please inspect element by Developer Tools. You will get from where its getting the bottom and top padding. Also try to put this code by disable the condition(i.e: if-else)

Comment: I have tried the inspect element tool. But it doesn't inspect the area which has extra white space.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by using these codes at base.html: `.navbar {
      margin-bottom: -40px;
      margin-top: -20px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }`